# Process.Start() doesn't work for gcc.exe/g++.exe

Tags: c#, winforms, gcc, process, g++

well, the title pretty much tells it:
I'm having trouble on using Process.Start() for

- gcc.exe
- g++.exe

but it's working just fine for everything else.

The code I'm using to set up my process (EDIT: Updated to full code):

`private void Compile(string path, string exe)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();`

```
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        if (path.EndsWith(".cpp") || path.EndsWith(".cxx") || path.EndsWith(".cc"))
        {
            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"compiler\MinGW64\bin");
            startInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"compiler\MinGW64\bin"), "g++.exe");

            if (exe.EndsWith(".exe"))
                startInfo.Arguments = string.Concat('"', path, '"') + " -o " + string.Concat('"', exe, '"') + " -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11";
            else
                startInfo.Arguments = string.Concat('"', path, '"') + " -o " + string.Concat('"', exe, ".exe", '"') + " -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11";
        }
        if (path.EndsWith(".c"))
        {
            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"compiler\MinGW64\bin");
            startInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"compiler\MinGW64\bin"), "gcc.exe");

            if (exe.EndsWith(".exe"))
                startInfo.Arguments = string.Concat('"', path, '"') + " -o " + string.Concat('"', exe, '"') + " -Wall -Wextra -std=c11";
            else
                startInfo.Arguments = string.Concat('"', path, '"') + " -o " + string.Concat('"', exe, ".exe", '"') + " -Wall -Wextra -std=c11";
        }
        if (path.EndsWith(".cs"))
        {
            startInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"compiler\v4.0.30319"), "csc.exe");

            if (exe.EndsWith(".exe"))
                startInfo.Arguments = "/out:" + string.Concat('"', exe, '"') + " /target:exe " + string.Concat('"', path, '"');
            else
                startInfo.Arguments = "/out:" + string.Concat('"', exe, ".exe", '"') + " /target:exe " + string.Concat('"', path, '"');
        }
        if(path.EndsWith(".vb"))
        {
            startInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"compiler\v4.0.30319"), "vbc.exe");

            if(exe.EndsWith(".exe"))
                startInfo.Arguments = "/out:" + string.Concat('"', exe, '"') + " /target:exe " + string.Concat('"', path, '"');
            else
                startInfo.Arguments = "/out:" + string.Concat('"', exe, ".exe", '"') + " /target:exe " + string.Concat('"', path, '"');
        }
        if(path.EndsWith(".il"))
        {
            startInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"compiler\v4.0.30319"), "ilasm.exe");

            if (exe.EndsWith(".exe"))
                startInfo.Arguments = string.Concat('"', path, '"') + " /EXE /OUTPUT:" + string.Concat('"', exe, '"');
            else
                startInfo.Arguments = string.Concat('"', path, '"') + " /EXE /OUTPUT:" + string.Concat('"', exe, ".exe", '"');
        }
        #endregion

        #region Launching compiler and redirect its stdout to a TextBox
        TCCompilerOutputOutputTextBox.Text += string.Concat(startInfo.FileName, ' ', startInfo.Arguments, "\r\n");

        try
        {
            using (Process comp = new Process()
            { StartInfo = startInfo, EnableRaisingEvents = true } )
            {
                try
                {
                    comp.ErrorDataReceived += Comp_InterceptOutput;
                    comp.OutputDataReceived += Comp_InterceptOutput;
                    comp.Start();

                    comp.BeginErrorReadLine();
                    comp.BeginOutputReadLine();

                    comp.WaitForExit();

                    TCCompilerOutputOutputTextBox.AppendText(OutputBuilder.ToString());
                    OutputBuilder.Clear();

                    TimeSpan time = comp.TotalProcessorTime;
                    var flag = !Convert.ToBoolean(comp.ExitCode);
                    if (flag)
                    {
                        TCCompilerOutputOutputTextBox.AppendText("\r\n\r\nCompilation finished after " + time + "\r\n" +
                            "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\n\r\n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TCCompilerOutputOutputTextBox.AppendText("\r\n\r\nCompilation failed!\r\n" +
                            "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\n\r\n");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var bfr = new ExceptionInformer(ex);

                    bfr.ShowDialog();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            var bfr = new ExceptionInformer(ex);

            bfr.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

I also tried to set the working directory, but nothing changes.

Variable-meaning:

- path (string): Full path to the file you want to compile
- exe (string): Full path to the compiled output

PS: I'm sorry if I forgot any necessary info, just ask if you're missing something :)

EDIT: 'trouble' means, gcc.exe doesn't start, but everything else does.

SOLUTION FOUND: I finally made it to work! gcc/g++ were complaining about a missing DLL, so I had the idea to additionally set the Working Directory (First I thought it was only necessary if you set UseShellExecute to 'true').
Updated to code to the working one.

Comment: "PS: I'm sorry if I forgot any necessary info, just ask if you're missing something"

Just one thing: what does "trouble" mean?

Comment: Ohh, sorry^^ 'trouble' means, that gcc.exe simply doesn't start up

Comment: Have you tried redirecting output so you can see what it says?

Comment: Yes, i did. This is what my TextBox tells me: [link](https://gyazo.com/058f433e7e2e3886a72ae5edbcfac279)

Comment: I'm betting you're not logging the inner exception from the failed compilation. What happens if you manually run that exact command? Does it compile?

Comment: It does compile, but only if I'm in the same directory. And how do I catch the exception thrown by another not-.net app?